# Macbook Pro M2 Ventura 13.2.1 can't recognize Brother DCP-T310

Tags: printing, ventura

I've had a Brother DCP-T310 for a while now. It's been running smoothly since 2019 through a Macbook Pro 2017 model. However, just today, when I tried it with a Macbook Pro M2 2022 on MacOS Ventura 13.2.1 it can't seem to find the driver/s that I downloaded from the Brother site and installed.

However, it can print using Brother's Iprint&Scan app.

Has anyone ever had this problem? thanks!

Comment: Try setting the 2017 MBP to share the printer. Then have the 2022 access the printer though the 2017 MBP. This may cause the 2022 MBP to download the driver.